# Python test if object exists

Tags: python, django, object, flow-control

I consider it bad style to use try: except: for flow control, but I can't figure out how to write the following code to test if a DB field in Django exists. This is the "dirty" code which works:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=UserProfile)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance=None, **kwargs):

    try:
        print str(instance.bank_account)
    except:
        print 'No account'
```

I would rather wanna do something like this, but I get an exception when the `if` statement is run and the object does not exist:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=UserProfile)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance=None, **kwargs):

    if instance.bank_account is None:
        print 'No account'
    else:
        print str(instance.bank_account)
```

Comment: Why would the field ever not exist?

Comment: before it was created and saved for the first time

Comment: Out of curiosity: are you following a project guideline or is it a personal preference? I'd consider your unqualified `except` bad style, but not if you used `except AttributeError`. I'd much prefer your first example to your second then.

Comment: Python is a language that encourages the 'ask for forgiveness, not permission' mantra. Unless you think it's more likely that the account won't exist most of the time, just catch a (specific) exception. http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you encounter a `BankAccount.DoesNotExist` error? If that's the case, you could reverse the relationship between `UserProfile` and `BankAccount`. Have a look at [Django ticket #10227](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10227) to find out what's going on here.

That being said, if I needed to work with your code I'd rather see an explicit `try...except` instead of a workaround, unless that workaround actually makes sense.

Comment: That ticket is describing my exact problem. Thx. I will use try: except DoesNotExist:

Answer (score 2):

I much prefer your first example to your second, but perhaps you could use `hasattr(instance,'bank_account')` as a safeguard?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your first example is the preferred way of doing this (although, you might like to narrow down the except to just the exceptions you expect for this operation).

I imagine that your if statement is blowing up when `instance is None`; the solution is to add a test to your if statement, to test `instance` first:

```
if instance and instance.bank_account:
    print str(instance.bank_account)
else: print 'No account'
```

If you don't know if the field exists, you could replace `instance.bank_account` with `getattr(instance, 'bank_account', None)`, which both retrieves the value, and deals with the possibility of the attribute not existing.